# TPL architectural question

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm currently working on a project, where we have the challenge to process items in parallel. So far not a big deal ;)
Now to the problem. We have a list of IDs, where we periodically (every 2 sec's) what to call a StoredProcedure for each ID.
The 2 sec's need to be checked for each item individually, as they are added and removing during runtime.
In addition we want to configure the maximum degree of parallelism, as the DB should not be flooded with 300 threads concurrently.
An item which is being processed should not be rescheduled for processing until it has finished with the previous execution. Reason is that we want to prevent queueing up a lot of items, in case of delays on the DB.

Right now we are using a self-developed component, that has a main thread, which periodically checks what items need to scheduled for processing. Once it has the list, it's dropping those on a custom IOCP-based thread pool, and then uses waithandles to wait for the items being processed. Then the next iteration starts. IOCP because of the work-stealing it provides.

I would like to replace this custom implementation with a TPL/.NET 4 version, and I would like to know how you would solve it (ideally simple and nicely readable/maintainable).
I know about this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx, but it's just limiting the amount of threads being used. Leaves work stealing, periodically executing the items ....

Ideally it will become a generic component, that can be used for some all the tasks that need to be done periodically for a list of items.

any input welcome,
tia
Martin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you actually need to get down and dirty with direct TPL [`Tasks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) for this. For starters I would set up a [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) around a [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) (the default) with no [`BoundedCapacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287159.aspx) set on the `BlockingCollection` to store the IDs that need to be processed.

```
// Setup the blocking collection somewhere when your process starts up (OnStart for a Windows service)
BlockingCollection<string> idsToProcess = new BlockingCollection<string>();
```

From there I would just use [`Parallel::ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) on the enumeration returned from the [`BlockingCollection::GetConsumingEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx). In the `ForEach` call you will setup your [`ParallelOptions::MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) Inside the body of the `ForEach` you will execute your stored procedure.

Now, once the stored procedure execution completes, you're saying you don't want to re-schedule the execution for *at least* two seconds. No problem, schedule a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) with a callback which will simply add the ID back to the `BlockingCollection` in the supplied callback.

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    idsToProcess.GetConsumingEnumerable(),
    new ParallelOptions 
    { 
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 // read this from config
    },
    (id) =>
    {
       // ... execute sproc ...

       // Need to declare/assign this before the delegate so that we can dispose of it inside 
       Timer timer = null;

       timer = new Timer(
           _ =>
           {
               // Add the id back to the collection so it will be processed again
               idsToProcess.Add(id);

               // Cleanup the timer
               timer.Dispose();
           },
           null, // no state, id wee need is "captured" in the anonymous delegate
           2000, // probably should read this from config
           Timeout.Infinite);
    }
```

Finally, when the process is shutting down you would call [`BlockingCollection::CompleteAdding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx) so that the enumerable being processed with stop blocking and complete and the Parallel::ForEach will exit. If this were a Windows service for example you would do this in [`OnStop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstop.aspx).

```
// When ready to shutdown you just signal you're done adding
idsToProcess.CompleteAdding();
```

**Update**

You raised a valid concern in your comment that you might be processing a large amount of IDs at any given point and fear that there would be too much overhead in a timer per ID. I would absolutely agree with that. So in the case that you are dealing with a large list of IDs concurrently, I would change from using a timer-per-ID to using another queue to hold the "sleeping" IDs which is monitored by a single short interval timer instead. First you'll need a `ConcurrentQueue` onto which to place the IDs that are asleep:

```
ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<string, DateTime>> sleepingIds = new ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<string, DateTime>>();
```

Now, I'm using a two-part [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) here for illustration purposes, but you may want to create a more strongly typed struct for it (or at least alias it with a `using` statement) for better readability. The tuple has the id and a DateTime which represents when it was put on the queue.

Now you'll also want to setup the timer that will monitor this queue:

```
Timer wakeSleepingIdsTimer = new Timer(
   _ =>
   {
       DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

       // Pull all items from the sleeping queue that have been there for at least 2 seconds
       foreach(string id in sleepingIds.TakeWhile(entry => (utcNow - entry.Item2).TotalSeconds >= 2))
       {
           // Add this id back to the processing queue
           idsToProcess.Enqueue(id);
       }
   },
   null, // no state
   Timeout.Infinite, // no due time
   100 // wake up every 100ms, probably should read this from config
 );
```

Then you would simply change the `Parallel::ForEach` to do the following instead of setting up a timer for each one:

```
(id) =>
{
       // ... execute sproc ...

       sleepingIds.Enqueue(Tuple.Create(id, DateTime.UtcNow)); 
}
```

Comment: nice idea, but don't you think that this will create a bit of a resource problem? I mean if I have e.g. 500 elements in the list, I'm a bit concerned about the big amount of timers running...

Comment: Thought about that, but you didn't give clear bounds so I was waiting for a response as to whether or not this met your needs. You can easily remedy this with another queue and single timer that monitors the queue for entries that are due and moves them back onto the main work queue. Will add details to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty similar to the approach you said you already had in your question, but does so with TPL tasks. A task just adds itself back to a list of things to schedule when its done.

The use of locking on a plain list is fairly ugly in this example, would probably want a better collection to hold the list of things to schedule

```
// Fill the idsToSchedule
for (int id = 0; id < 5; id++)
{
    idsToSchedule.Add(Tuple.Create(DateTime.MinValue, id));
}

// LongRunning will tell TPL to create a new thread to run this on
Task.Factory.StartNew(SchedulingLoop, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

That starts up the SchedulingLoop, which actually performs the checking if its been two seconds since something ran

```
// Tuple of the last time an id was processed and the id of the thing to schedule
static List<Tuple<DateTime, int>> idsToSchedule = new List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>();
static int currentlyProcessing = 0;
const int ProcessingLimit = 3;

// An event loop that performs the scheduling
public static void SchedulingLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock (idsToSchedule)
        {
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            for (int index = idsToSchedule.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
            {
                var scheduleItem = idsToSchedule[index];
                var timeSincePreviousRun = (currentTime - scheduleItem.Item1).TotalSeconds;

                // start it executing in a background task
                if (timeSincePreviousRun > 2 && currentlyProcessing < ProcessingLimit)
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref currentlyProcessing);

                    Console.WriteLine("Scheduling {0} after {1} seconds", scheduleItem.Item2, timeSincePreviousRun);

                    // Schedule this task to be processed
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Executing {0}", scheduleItem.Item2);

                            // simulate the time taken to call this procedure
                            Thread.Sleep(new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(0, 5000) + 500);

                            lock (idsToSchedule)
                            {
                                idsToSchedule.Add(Tuple.Create(DateTime.Now, scheduleItem.Item2));
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine("Done Executing {0}", scheduleItem.Item2);
                            Interlocked.Decrement(ref currentlyProcessing);
                        });

                    // remove this from the list of things to schedule
                    idsToSchedule.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```