# Parallel ForEach, and Queues

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Is it possible to have a parallel for each loop process the items in a queue such that it:

1. only removes items that are being processed
2. Pauses until new items are added to the queue

EDIT: This is in regards to System.Threading.Tasks' Parallel.ForEach functionality

Comment: Check out this question too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308225/tpl-architectural-question

Comment: Nah the answer's for that question is too complex. Reactive Programming is the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subscribe to the queue using Reactive Extensions and execute each item in a new task.
You won't have to block or wait for new item since it will be pushed on to your subscribe lambda and your execution/processing would be parallel.

http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples

Comment: Ok so it's the Reactive Programming model and RX is an implementation of that. Thanks Hasan

Answer (score 1):

Use BlockingCollection something like this:

```
    var bc = new BlockingCollection<int>();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 30
            };
        Parallel.ForEach(bc.GetConsumingEnumerable(), options, i => { });
    });
```

Comment: Therefore the task will wait until new items are placed into the collection before continuing correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be possible if the queue concrete implementation is synchronized, basically this is a consumer-producer scenario.

Comment: Uh? Sorry I didn't understand that at all :(

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to iterate the same queue in 2 different for each loops right?, so basically you would have two threads each doing its for each loop, for this to work the queue would have to support synchronization between the threads.

Comment: Oh, sorry I was refering to System.Threading.Tasks' Parallel.ForEach functionality.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry don't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about a classic producer/consumer situation.  It always surprises me that there's not more direct support for this model built into .Net.  The closest I've come across in .Net was at one time hidden away inside concurrency and coordination runtime, which was part of the Microsoft Robotics suite.  Good luck finding it now.

But once you know what to search for, a quick Google check does provide a few other potential options.